# Use fixed day in calculation of completely paid of dept

Tags: date, google-sheets

I'm using this code to calculate when I have completely paid off on a dept.

`F26+(30*B6/F6)`

This prints for example `2015-06-12`. I'm not receiving any money until the end of the month.  Is it possible to have a fixed day but not for the year and month, so I can have the day fixed to for example `28`? If yes, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: what are `F26`, `B6`, `F6` that yielded result `2015-06-12` in your example?

Comment: @har07 `F26` is the date I started to pay off my depts (for example `2014-06-18`). `B6` is the total sum (for example `2 405`), and `F6` is the sum I pay to the company each month (for example `200`)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution I can imagine is using [`DATE(YEAR, MONTH, DAY)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969) function to construct date with fixed `DAY`, for example :

```
DATE(YEAR(F26+(30*B6/F6)), MONTH(F26+(30*B6/F6)), 28)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but I'm getting `#ERROR!` (processing issues) :/

Comment: Work for me in simplified scenario [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14eYdPspBfGfgAzGSU3m151OfS0eS2WPfaL9D0qjYeRI/edit?usp=sharing) (or maybe I misunderstood your problem)

Comment: Hm. That's wierd that it works for you but not for me. I write my dates like this: `2014-05-28`. But that shouldn't be the problem. Not even a simple `=DATE(2014, 05, 28)` works O.o